# Old Laptop Dell Precision M4300 will work well with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS?

Tags: lubuntu, dell

I have an old laptop Dell Precision M4300, with Intel Core 2 Duo T9300 2.50GHz, 3,50 Gb RAM, HD IDE 150Gb.

I have it with XP, the pc is working very good but I feel unsafe still using it with this OS.

I read in in the official Ubuntu site that the minimun requirements that this PC have will work good with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, but they advice that with IDE HD it could be slow, so they suggest to use Xubuntu or Lubuntu.
I used both of them in older compuyters but I am not very happy with them, I would like to have Ubuntu latest version if possible.

As your experience, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS will work well in this Dell Precision M4300 that I described?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your computer will work "well" with Ubuntu 14.04.2 but it mostly depends on what you expect as a definition for the words: "work well".

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad T400 which has an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600  @ 2.40GHz, 3 GB RAM and 160 GB HDD and I can work with the majority of the tasks I have to face for the day to day work and let's have in consideration that what I do for a living (nowadays) includes (but not limits only to):

1. HTML/CSS/Javascript coding via [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/)
2. [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) deployment via LAMP
3. Graphic design with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and [Krita](https://krita.org/), sometimes [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)
4. Photography retouch with [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/)
5. Audio mastering/authoring with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), [Linux Multimedia Studio](https://lmms.io/)
   (lmms) and other tools.
6. Electronic Music creation (like those mentioned on
   http://geppettvs.x10.mx/la-musica/) with the previously mentioned
   tools.
7. Video Edition with [OpenShot](http://openshot.org/) and [KDEnlive](https://kdenlive.org/). (Samples here:
   https://www.youtube.com/user/geppettvs/videos)
8. DVD Authoring with [DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/)
9. And some other useful things.

Of course I cannot multi-task with this computer, not beyond 4 or 5 of these software running at once. And audio renders are yet good for high quality audio but... Let's face it. HD Video editing is a nightmare. Specially when we include a lot of transitions, layers, sound effects, video processing, etc.

But... Look at this!

[image]

At this very moment I am writing this with 11 tabs open in my Firefox instance, a terminal (idle), playing music via radiotray, haguichi doing its magic for a VPN, bluetooth enabled and I experience no issues at all.

My desktop environment -nevertheless- was changed from a fully eye-candy decorated Unity (2D or Normal) to a i3 Tiling Window Manager (https://i3wm.org/) which improves the overall speed when it is about productivity. For eye-candy and to impress your friends you may wish a fancier desktop environment like Unity or KDE and probably the usage of Compiz but they're high resource hungry, so I won't recommend to use it in a computer like this.

For what is about the IDE HDD, I would just say that if the HDD is in good condition you may yet find it fast enough to do everything I mentioned over here.

But, that's my own experience. What if -let's say- you give it a try and inform us on your results? It will be great for the community!

Thank you for reading and Good luck!

Comment: You cleared all my doubts about that so thank you very much! The most heavy things that I could do with it will be some Gimp use or video/audio play, office or so. So I think it will work just great! I will go for it in the next days.

Comment: Please give us some feedback about your experiences and if you face some issues previous to/during/after install don't hesitate to open a new question and bring a comment here with the link of the new question in order to follow up your issues. Good luck!

Comment: I am writing this comment from the brand new installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS over the mentioned laptop Dell Precision M4300, and it is working really great!! Everything seems going very good. The installation was straightforward from bootable USB pen. I am very happy with it. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Glad to know you succeeded on the install process. Don't forget to let us know on your experiences with this equipment and if need further help open a new question. Lots of people will be around to provide useful hints and tips for almost any situation. Good luck!